# Returning Array contents instead of memory address

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return-value

So I'm trying to return the contents of an array in a method.
Lets assume this array is called x and it already has values in it.

```
    public int[] returnArray()
     {
       return x;
      }
```

Now, I know that this will return the memory address of the array. So I tried this workaround I saw earlier:

```
    public int[] returnArray()
     {
      int[] y=new int[x.length]
       for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
       {
         y[i]=x[i]
       }
       return y;
      }
```

Now, this is also returning the memory address of the array. Is there no workaround for this?

Comment: You can't. Java does not have concept of object values.

Comment: Are you trying to print it maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return x;` returns a reference to the array, which gives you access to all the elements of the array.

You probably think you got the "memory address of the array" because you tried to print the array with `System.out.println(returnArray());`, which doesn't display the elements of the array. You should print the array with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(returnArray()));`

Comment: Ah okay. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't return anything but the address because what you can return is only *one* value. An array often contains more than one value.

You could return the value at position 0 of the array for example, but not all the different values at once.

And whoever posted that "workaround" obviously has no clue. This creates another array and copies the content from the original array into the new array, then returns *that* array's address.

However, you don't need to return the elements of an array, the array reference allows you to access the elements.

`returnArray()[0]` gets the first element of the returned array (reference).

To print the elements, you can iterate over the array:

```
for (int x : returnArray()) { 
  System.out.println(x);
}
```